# Quick Delta Between Two Rows/Columns in GoodData

Tags: gooddata

Right now, I see there are quick ways to get things like Sum/Avg/Max/Etc. for two or more rows or columns when building a table in GoodData.

[quick total options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PM3XV.jpg)

I am building a little table that shows last week and the week prior, and I'm trying to show the delta between them.

So if the first column is 100 and the second is 50, I want '-50'
If the first column is 25 and the second is 100, i want '75'

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Let’s consider, that the first column contains result of calculating of metric #1 and the second column contains result of calculating of metric #2, you can simply create a metric #3, which would be defined as the (metric #1 - metric #2) or vice versa.